# Auto role when someone is playing?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get my bot to automatically add someone to a role when they start a game, and remove it from that role when they leave the game.

I have already tried several things but without success :

Some other bot change activity but I do not want the other bots of my server to be added in the role so I did that (and it seems to work):

```
let roleid = "ROLE BOT ID" 

if (newMember.roles.has(roleid)) {}
else {console.log("my code here")}
```

I have the impression that discord.js "gathers" people who play a game (on desktop) and people connected to mobile. So I try to separate them like that but the "! =" does not seem to work :

```
if (newMember.presence.clientStatus = 'desktop') {console.log("my code here")}
```

Then I have one last problem is that my bot adds me to the role when I leave my game

Here is my whole code

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
let guildChannels = newMember.guild;
let roleid = "ROLE BOT ID" 

if (newMember.roles.has(roleid)) {}
else {
 if (newMember.presence.clientStatus = 'desktop') {
  if (newMember.presence.ActivityType = 'PLAYING') {
   newMember.addRole(newMember.guild.roles.find (x => x.id == 'PLAYING ROLE ID'))
  console.log(newMember.user.tag + ' -> "ROLE PLAYING NAME"')
}
else {newMember.removeRole(newMember.guild.roles.find (x => x.id ==     'PLAYING ROLE ID'))
    console.log(newMember.user.tag + ' / "ROLE PLAYING NAME"')
   }
  }
 }

});
```

I'd like my bot to add all the people playing a role, and delete them when they're done playing

I do not have an error message only that my bot is not doing exactly what I want and I do not have an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```js
> if (newMember.presence.clientStatus = 'desktop') {console.log("my code here")}
> ```
>
> ```js
> if (newMember.presence.ActivityType = 'PLAYING') {
> ```

The reason these pieces of code don't work is because you're using the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) `=` instead of a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) like `===` or `==`. Essentially, the code is *setting* the properties instead of *comparing* them.

*Use comparison operators to check the values of properties, not assignment operators.*

---

`Presence.ActivityType` is not a valid property of [Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence).

*Check the user's game ([`Presence.game`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=game)) to see if they're playing something.*

---

> Some other bot change activity but I do not want the other bots of my server to be added in the role...

*Check if a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) is a bot with the [`User.bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot) property.*

---

If a user changes their status (i.e. Online --> DND) or starts listening to music, watching a stream, etc., your code will be executed even though their game has not changed.

*You need to check the old presence and compare it with the new presence to make sure the user started or stopped playing a game.*

---

You aren't catching any rejected [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

*Use [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statements or attach [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) methods to Promises.*

---

**Code**

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const guild = newMember.guild;
  const playingRole = guild.roles.find(role => role.id === 'PLAYING ROLE ID');

  if (newMember.user.bot || newMember.presence.clientStatus === 'mobile' || oldMember.presence.status !== newMember.presence.status) return;

  const oldGame = oldMember.presence.game && [0, 1].includes(oldMember.presence.game.type) ? true : false;
  const newGame = newMember.presence.game && [0, 1].includes(newMember.presence.game.type) ? true : false;

  if (!oldGame && newGame) {         // Started playing.
    newMember.addRole(playingRole)
      .then(() => console.log(`${playingRole.name} added to ${newMember.user.tag}.`))
      .catch(console.error);
  } else if (oldGame && !newGame) {  // Stopped playing.
    newMember.removeRole(playingRole)
      .then(() => console.log(`${playingRole.name} removed from ${newMember.user.tag}.`))
      .catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! There were too many mistakes to correct ... But as a "beginner", I learn a little more each day :)

Comment: Learning is what it's all about. You can't learn without mistakes. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Oh I had another little problem .. Users listening to music on spotify or being watching a stream are also included 

I tried this : 

`if (newMember.user.bot || newMember.presence.clientStatus === 'mobile' || newMember.presence.game == null) return;
if (newMember.presence.game.type == '0') {my code}`

But suddenly when users leave their game, the presence is counted as 'null' and does not apply the rest of the code

Comment: See the edited code. It's checking the [`type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Game?scrollTo=type) property of [`Game`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Game) to make sure they're playing or streaming.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I forgot to specify that when the user does not do anything anymore, the ".type" will return a "null" which makes the bot crash

Comment: The edited version checks that they're playing a game before the type. If they're playing a game *and* their status type is "playing" or "streaming," then the corresponding old/new game variables are defined. Otherwise, if their presence doesn't include a game at all, or they're not "playing" or "streaming," it's null. That way, it's incorporated when checking in the `if` statements.

Comment: So in the current code, it is impossible to differentiate a user who plays or stream from a user who listens to music or watches a stream ?

Comment: What's shown right now is doing that. Only games being played or streamed will trigger the role system.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, as I'm not English, chat using google translation is more complicated ... My friend is listening to music on spotify and the bot has still added it to the role. I'm confused

Comment: You would've received an error if you were using the edited code (fixed now). Testing with this code, I don't receive the same results. Use the code shown in the post now.

Comment: I feel that it works. Thank you very much once again. I think it was not my level yet ..

Comment: Updated the code once again to prevent it from being run twice when a user comes online or goes offline while playing a game. Glad I could help.